# Blurry Image on API 21+ : AppCompat v23.2.0 using VectorDrawables with srcCompat

Tags: android, imageview, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

**I have an image display issue on API 21+, but everything works fine on lower devices and API 22+.** I'm using Gradle Plugin 1.5, so my `build.gradle` look like this:

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

**Image View in XML:**

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/landing_img_slide"
   android:layout_width="225dp"
   android:layout_height="225dp"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

**Java Code :**

```
ImageView iconView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.landing_img_slide);
iconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.laptopscreen);
```

**Below Screenshots will shows `ImageView` with VectorDrawable works fine with Pre-lollipop and Marshmallow but shows Blurry Image in Android 5.0.1**

**Android 4.4.4**
[image: Android 4.4.4 Screenshot]

**Android 5.0.1**

[image: Android 5.0.1 Screenshot]

**Android 6.0.1**

[image: Android 6.0.1 Screenshot]

Comment: and where is your java code?

Comment: @pskink I have updated the Java code, currently i am using java code in this layout. but in other layout i am using vector in XML still i am getting blurry images in API 21+

Comment: What happens when you use 23.2.1?

Comment: @ianhanniballake still same effect. I tried 23.2.1 too.

Comment: seems you have some generated pngs hanging around, check it out

Comment: @pskink , I think so there are no such extra pngs generated, as i already cleaned the project and re-build it.

Comment: @DanielNugent, I already mentioned this solutions drawback in Lewis McGeary answer.

Comment: What's your vector width, height, viewportWidth and viewportHeight?

Comment: `android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="200.0"
    android:viewportWidth="200.0"
    android:width="24dp"` . @EugenPechanec I don't think it matters when your `ImageView` is match_parent

Comment: then `Log.d` the value of `iconView.getDrawable()`

Comment: @pskink `E/iconView: ->android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable@3677f6a8`

Comment: `android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable` was added in API 21 so how can you see it on Android 4.4 API 19?

Comment: earlier log i was getting on Android 5.0.1 and on Android 4.4 i am getting `E/iconView: ->android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat@42d73fb8`

Comment: use [this](http://pastebin.com/DwPYFKJD) to get the `VectorDrawableCompat`

Comment: @pskink, solutions provided by you will be ideal when i am dynamically setting vector in imagwview. What about in xml?

Comment: you cannot do that trick in xml: you have to create a custom ImageView and load the Drawable by yourself (as i posted in above link)

Comment: actualy it should be `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`, not `android.widget.ImageView` that should be extended

Comment: @pskink what if i use only `AppCompatImageView` in place of `ImageView` for vector drawables in XML?

Comment: you can do that but then you need to `findViewById` manually and call `setImageDrawable` by yourself, it doesnt pay off

Comment: my question is using `AppCompatImageView` will solve my problem of blurry images on API 21+

Comment: no, `AppCompatImageView` does not help by itself, when using it you still have to load the `VectorDrawable` in the way i posted in the link above, just extend it and call my `create()` method in the constructor

Answer (score 3):

This is to do with the scaleType in your ImageView which does inconsistent things at these different API levels when it comes to VectorDrawables.

There is one scaleType which seems to consistently give a sharp image when scaling: `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but when using this you have to ensure that the ImageView has the same aspect ratio as the Vector Drawable (eg. if you use fitXY with a square VectorDrawable and a rectangular ImageView it will stretch the image out).

Alternatively you can change the size in the VectorDrawable itself by setting

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="225dp"
android:height="225dp"
.../>
```

By doing this there will be no scaling necessary in the ImageView.

Comment: it does solve my problem when 'width' and `height` are fixed. But when 'ImageView' as dynamic 'width' and `height` that is `match_parent` or `wrap_content`. Your solution doesn't work. As it creates mess of image in imageview.