# Why my SVG image looks blurry in device API 16 and API 27

Tags: android

I had generated a 96x96 SVG image via Android Studio.

[image]

Then, I apply SVG file in the following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clickable="false"

            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_content_paste_black_24dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clickable="false"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tap_to_add_note"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Take note that,

1. I use `app:srcCompat` in `ImageView`
2. I has added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795933/72437
3. I use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930518/72437

It looks both blurry in API 27 and API 16.

### API 27

[image]

### API 16

[image]

### Note

You will notice the icon is in grey color instead of black color. This is because I had applied

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(this.imageView.getDrawable(), greyIconColor);
```

However, I'm not sure why API 16 doesn't appear as grey.

My build.gradle file looks like

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yocto.noteplus"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
```

### SVG File

My SVG file content is

```
<vector android:height="96dp" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:width="96dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M19,2h-4.18C14.4,0.84 13.3,0 12,0c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,2c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v16c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,2c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1s-0.45,1 -1,1 -1,-0.45 -1,-1 0.45,-1 1,-1zM19,20L5,20L5,4h2v3h10L17,4h2v16z"/>
</vector>
```

---

### Extra note

You may run the actual device to see the blurry, or use the **Screen Capture** in Logcat to see the blurry effect.

[image]

***May I know, why my SVG image looks blurry in device API 16 and API 27?***

Comment: See if this is of any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016596/blurry-image-on-api-21-appcompat-v23-2-0-using-vectordrawables-with-srccompat, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936590/why-isnt-my-vector-drawable-scaling-as-expected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548354/vectordrawable-is-it-available-somehow-for-pre-lollipop-versions-of-android

Comment: I tried your layout and vector drawable on an Android Studio emulator running API 16 (Pixel 6) and on another emulator running API 27 (Pixel 5X) and the images are sharp and clear. Can you 1) be more specific about where you are seeing the blurry images? Are these real devices or emulations? What kind of emulation or device?, and, 2) maybe put up a project that exhibits the blurriness? Is the image clear on APIs other then 16 and 27? Otherwise, it is going to be difficult to find the problem.

Comment: @Cheticamp You need to run on actual device, or use the Screen Capture in Logcat to see the blurry effect. See my updated question.

Comment: I'd advise to change vector's `android:height`/`android:width` to be the same as `android:viewportHeight`/`android:viewportWidth`. In your case `android:height="24dp"` and `android:width="24dp"`. The image will still be `96dp` x `96dp` Because you apply that size to `ImageView`

Comment: Found an old LG phone running API 16. Unfortunately, the graphic looks clear and sharp on that device and in a screen capture, so it is not just being on API 16 that is the problem.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue. Unfortunately I couldn't achieve that. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X78WE.png) a screenshot of Nexus S API 16. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU9Av.png) a screenshot of Nexus 5X API 27.

Comment: Trouble reproducing the problem. If you have a sample project that demonstrates this problem, it would be very helpful. Are you on the latest releases of Android Studio and Gradle?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng are you running API 16 on hardware or an emulator ?? if it is hardware, maybe try to run it on the emulator once - in order to rule out any device-specific quirks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered similar issues before. In my case, it was due to having both `SVG` & `PNG` files with `same name`, under `drawable` folder.

As you can see below, I am having `ic_content_paste_black_24dp.png` & `ic_content_paste_black_24dp.xml (SVG)`.

[image]

So when we specify:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_content_paste_black_24dp" />
```

System got confused & pick up the `PNG` file, as no `file extension` is specified.

Android should consider to allow specifying file extension to avoid such confusion.

Comment: Exactly! How careless I was, to let such problem happens. Now recheck my project, and I realize I previously contains 5 different dpi PNG, before creating another SVG with same name. Thanks Shuwn!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I accidentally used `android:src` instead of `android:srcCompat`, which you don't want to use for SVGs.

Here you can find more information about the differences between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624625/10226383